# How to make cursor ignores pseudo elements in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Firefox, if cursor starts like this

```
`123`|
```

and I press left arrow 2 times, I want it to land on the left side of `2`:

```
 `1|23`
```

as it would have if the pseudo element wasn't there.

Any ideas?

```css
.code {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.pseudo-ele::after {
  content: "3";
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <span>`</span><span class="code pseudo-ele">12</span><span>`</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s exactly where it does land. I’m on a Mac, and tests just fine in Safari and Chrome. Didn’t work in Firefox, though, perhaps Firefox has issues with having `contenteditable` inside an `<iframe>`? (which it is when using stack snippets)

Comment: @BrettDonald, for me -- Brave on Linux Mint -- the same happens.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention my browser - Firefox

Comment: That feature is unfortunately still under-specified and we're far from interop. What happens here is that FF does allow going to either the end of the previous element by moving the caret to the right, or to the beginning of the next one by moving the caret to the left. You can see this by coloring both elements differently: https://jsfiddle.net/m9qfwy72/ From this feature their behavior when there is a pseudo-element in between kind of makes sense. Unfortunately I don't see any workaround...

Answer (score -1):

This is not working because the `contenteditable` is allowing the editing of the HTML itself, so the pseudo-element is being edited too. You will have to change the way you edit your HTML on your page to allow it to work on FireFox.

To fix this issue on all browsers besides Firefox, use this method:

```css
.code {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.pseudo-ele::after {
  content: "3";
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <span>`</span><span class="code pseudo-ele">12</span><span>`</span>
</div>
```